# Merging multiple CSV files using the date column when dates are different

Tags: r, csv

I have many csv files in a folder which are arranged into four columns. Here is an example with DatA.csv.

| Date | positivity | Polarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-Jun-97 | 10 | 30 |
| 26-Jun-97 | 20 | 31 |
| 07-Jul-97 | 22 | 27 |

The column date has different observations in each of those csv files. For example, dataset B has the following:

(datB.csv)

| Date | positivity | Polarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14-Jun-97 | 14 | 17 |

I want to combine all the polarity columns from the csv files into one using the "date" variable, while keeping the filename. For example the above would be

| Date | datA | Polarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-Jun-97 | 30 |  |
| 14-Jun-97 |  | 18 |
| 26-Jun-97 | 31 |  |
| 07-Jul-97 | 27 |  |

I am not sure if I should be using `left_join`?

Answer (score 1):

If your dates (keys) occur in multiple csv files, and you want to retain them all plus combine the data for the same date in multiple csvs, you could use an outer join (i.e., `merge(..., all = TRUE)`.  More on joins [here](https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/join-in-r-merge-in-r/).

If dates are unique between csv files, you don't need to join; you can just `rbind`, like this:

```
library(dplyr)

files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
files
#> [1] "DatA.csv" "DatB.csv"
output <- data.frame()

for(file in files){
  f <- read.csv(file)
  f[,file] <- f$polarity
  output <- dplyr::bind_rows(output, f)
}
output
#>   X      Date positivity polarity DatA.csv DatB.csv
#> 1 1 12-Jun-97         10       30       30       NA
#> 2 2 26-Jun-97         20       31       31       NA
#> 3 3 07-Jul-97         22       27       27       NA
#> 4 1 14-Jun-97         14       18       NA       18

Created on 2021-10-06 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Data:

```
DatA.csv <- data.frame(
  Date = c("12-Jun-97", "26-Jun-97", "07-Jul-97"),
  positivity = c(10, 20, 22),
  polarity = c(30, 31, 27))

DatB.csv <- data.frame(Date = "14-Jun-97", positivity = 14, polarity = 18)

write.csv(DatA.csv, "DatA.csv")
write.csv(DatB.csv, "DatB.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is so helpful. This was exactly what I was looking for. Perhaps I was overthinking the problem.

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck